# How to stretch content vertically with grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid template. I want to stretch content to the end but I can't do it. Behaves unexpectedly. I want to use CSS Grid.

I applied `display: grid` to the body.

Note: Do not bother with `::after` thing. I want to make a japordy game, when User click a box, It will show the question. But it is not my question.

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20%);

    height: 100vh;
}

.question-block {
      /* not doing the trick */
        grid-row: 1/-1;
}
```

Here is the code snippet.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20%);

    height: 100vh;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

.question-block {
  /* not doing the trick */
    grid-row: 1/-1;
}

.question-block * {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.category {
    padding: 1em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: max(1rem, min(1rem + 3vw, 3.5rem));
}

.question {
    font-size: 0;
}

.q100::after {
    content: "100$";
}

.q200::after {
    content: "200$";
}

.q300::after {
    content: "300$";
}

.q400::after {
    content: "400$";
}

.text-helper::after {
    display: block;
    padding-block: 0;

    text-align: center;
    font-size: max(1.5rem, min(1rem + 3vw, 5rem));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
    <title>Jeopardy</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="question-block">
        <p class="category">Entertainment: Television</p>
        <p class="question q100 text-helper">AMC's "The Walking Dead", Rick, Carl, Daryl, Morgan, Carol and Maggie were
            introduced to us in Season 1.</p>
        <p class="question q200 text-helper">In the TV series Red Dwarf, Kryten's full name is Kryten 2X4B-523P.</p>
        <p class="question q300 text-helper">Like his character in "Parks and Recreation", Aziz Ansari was born in South
            Carolina.</p>
        <p class="question q400 text-helper">In "Star Trek", Klingons respect William Shakespeare, they even suspect him
            having a Klingon lineage.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question-block">
        <p class="category">Science: Computers</p>
        <p class="question q100 text-helper">The very first recorded computer "bug" was a moth found inside a Harvard
            Mark II computer.</p>
        <p class="question q200 text-helper">Linus Torvalds created Linux and Git.</p>
        <p class="question q300 text-helper">It's not possible to format a write-protected DVD-R Hard Disk.</p>
        <p class="question q400 text-helper">The Python programming language gets its name from the British comedy group
            "Monty Python."</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question-block">
        <p class="category">Vehicles</p>
        <p class="question q100 text-helper">Arriva is owned by the Deutsche Bahn.</p>
        <p class="question q200 text-helper">Ferrari has never made a V10 engine for any of its cars.</p>
        <p class="question q300 text-helper">The General Motors EV1 was the first street-legal production electric
            vehicle.</p>
        <p class="question q400 text-helper">BMW M GmbH is a subsidiary of BMW AG that focuses on car performance.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question-block">
        <p class="category">Entertainment: Board Games</p>
        <p class="question q100 text-helper">In the game "Racko" you may pick up ANY card from the discard pile.</p>
        <p class="question q200 text-helper">The Angry Video Game Nerd's alter ego is "Board James".</p>
        <p class="question q300 text-helper">"PAYDAY: The Heist" is a sequel to the board game "Payday".</p>
        <p class="question q400 text-helper">The board game Go has more possible legal positions than the number of
            atoms in the visible universe.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- <script src="js/index.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

If I change `.question-block` to `display: grid` it causes content overlapping.

Here:

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20%);

        height: 100vh;
    }

    p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .question-block {
      /* not doing the trick */
      
      /* only change here */
      display: grid;
      /* above */
      
        grid-row: 1/-1;
    }

    .question-block * {
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

    .category {
        padding: 1em;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        font-size: max(1rem, min(1rem + 3vw, 3.5rem));
    }

    .question {
        font-size: 0;
    }

    .q100::after {
        content: "100$";
    }

    .q200::after {
        content: "200$";
    }

    .q300::after {
        content: "300$";
    }

    .q400::after {
        content: "400$";
    }

    .text-helper::after {
        display: block;
        padding-block: 0;

        text-align: center;
        font-size: max(1.5rem, min(1rem + 3vw, 5rem));
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
        <title>Jeopardy</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="question-block">
            <p class="category">Entertainment: Television</p>
            <p class="question q100 text-helper">AMC's "The Walking Dead", Rick, Carl, Daryl, Morgan, Carol and Maggie were
                introduced to us in Season 1.</p>
            <p class="question q200 text-helper">In the TV series Red Dwarf, Kryten's full name is Kryten 2X4B-523P.</p>
            <p class="question q300 text-helper">Like his character in "Parks and Recreation", Aziz Ansari was born in South
                Carolina.</p>
            <p class="question q400 text-helper">In "Star Trek", Klingons respect William Shakespeare, they even suspect him
                having a Klingon lineage.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="question-block">
            <p class="category">Science: Computers</p>
            <p class="question q100 text-helper">The very first recorded computer "bug" was a moth found inside a Harvard
                Mark II computer.</p>
            <p class="question q200 text-helper">Linus Torvalds created Linux and Git.</p>
            <p class="question q300 text-helper">It's not possible to format a write-protected DVD-R Hard Disk.</p>
            <p class="question q400 text-helper">The Python programming language gets its name from the British comedy group
                "Monty Python."</p>
        </div>
        <div class="question-block">
            <p class="category">Vehicles</p>
            <p class="question q100 text-helper">Arriva is owned by the Deutsche Bahn.</p>
            <p class="question q200 text-helper">Ferrari has never made a V10 engine for any of its cars.</p>
            <p class="question q300 text-helper">The General Motors EV1 was the first street-legal production electric
                vehicle.</p>
            <p class="question q400 text-helper">BMW M GmbH is a subsidiary of BMW AG that focuses on car performance.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="question-block">
            <p class="category">Entertainment: Board Games</p>
            <p class="question q100 text-helper">In the game "Racko" you may pick up ANY card from the discard pile.</p>
            <p class="question q200 text-helper">The Angry Video Game Nerd's alter ego is "Board James".</p>
            <p class="question q300 text-helper">"PAYDAY: The Heist" is a sequel to the board game "Payday".</p>
            <p class="question q400 text-helper">The board game Go has more possible legal positions than the number of
                atoms in the visible universe.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- <script src="js/index.js"></script> -->
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Use `display: grid` with the trick that don't work

Comment: @Rana but it causes content overlapping. See new added code snippet example.

Comment: This may be because you have not correctly defined `width`'s or need to be changed which causes this rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out.

I covered all questions with a `<div class="questions">` and applied this styling on it.

```css
.questions {
        height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 17%);
    }
```

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20%);

        height: 100vh;
    }

    p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .question-block {
      /* not doing the trick */
      
      /* only change here */
      display: grid;
      /* above */
      
        grid-row: 1/-1;
    }

    .question-block * {
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

  .category {
    height: 35%;
    padding: 0.3em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: max(1rem, min(1rem + 3vw, 3rem));
}

.questions {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 20%);
}

    .question {
        font-size: 0;
    }

    .q100::after {
        content: "100$";
    }

    .q200::after {
        content: "200$";
    }

    .q300::after {
        content: "300$";
    }

    .q400::after {
        content: "400$";
    }

    .text-helper::after {
        display: block;
        padding-block: 0;

        text-align: center;
        font-size: max(1.5rem, min(1rem + 3vw, 5rem));
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
        <title>Jeopardy</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="question-block">
            <p class="category">Television</p>
            <div class="questions">
            <p class="question q100 text-helper">AMC's "The Walking Dead", Rick, Carl, Daryl, Morgan, Carol and Maggie were
                introduced to us in Season 1.</p>
            <p class="question q200 text-helper">In the TV series Red Dwarf, Kryten's full name is Kryten 2X4B-523P.</p>
            <p class="question q300 text-helper">Like his character in "Parks and Recreation", Aziz Ansari was born in South
                Carolina.</p>
            <p class="question q400 text-helper">In "Star Trek", Klingons respect William Shakespeare, they even suspect him
                having a Klingon lineage.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="question-block">
            <p class="category">Television</p>
            <div class="questions">
            <p class="question q100 text-helper">AMC's "The Walking Dead", Rick, Carl, Daryl, Morgan, Carol and Maggie were
                introduced to us in Season 1.</p>
            <p class="question q200 text-helper">In the TV series Red Dwarf, Kryten's full name is Kryten 2X4B-523P.</p>
            <p class="question q300 text-helper">Like his character in "Parks and Recreation", Aziz Ansari was born in South
                Carolina.</p>
            <p class="question q400 text-helper">In "Star Trek", Klingons respect William Shakespeare, they even suspect him
                having a Klingon lineage.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="question-block">
            <p class="category">Television</p>
            <div class="questions">
            <p class="question q100 text-helper">AMC's "The Walking Dead", Rick, Carl, Daryl, Morgan, Carol and Maggie were
                introduced to us in Season 1.</p>
            <p class="question q200 text-helper">In the TV series Red Dwarf, Kryten's full name is Kryten 2X4B-523P.</p>
            <p class="question q300 text-helper">Like his character in "Parks and Recreation", Aziz Ansari was born in South
                Carolina.</p>
            <p class="question q400 text-helper">In "Star Trek", Klingons respect William Shakespeare, they even suspect him
                having a Klingon lineage.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="question-block">
            <p class="category">Television</p>
            <div class="questions">
            <p class="question q100 text-helper">AMC's "The Walking Dead", Rick, Carl, Daryl, Morgan, Carol and Maggie were
                introduced to us in Season 1.</p>
            <p class="question q200 text-helper">In the TV series Red Dwarf, Kryten's full name is Kryten 2X4B-523P.</p>
            <p class="question q300 text-helper">Like his character in "Parks and Recreation", Aziz Ansari was born in South
                Carolina.</p>
            <p class="question q400 text-helper">In "Star Trek", Klingons respect William Shakespeare, they even suspect him
                having a Klingon lineage.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- <script src="js/index.js"></script> -->
    </body>

    </html>
```